# Postgres - Same query returns different results when run again and again

Tags: postgresql, limit

While experimenting PostgreSQL for my new project, I have experienced the following query execution behavior. I would like to know why the same query returns different values when run again and again? What is the rational behind this behavior?

```
phi=# SELECT P.id, p.resource ->> 'birthDate' BD FROM recorditems P WHERE  P.resource @> '{"resourceType":"Patient", "gender":"male"}' AND To_date(P.resource ->> 'birthDate', 'YYYY-MM-DD') > '1975-01-01'::date limit 10;
   id   |     bd
--------+------------
 363661 | 1990-03-08
 363752 | 2006-02-28
 364971 | 2017-10-21
 365330 | 1996-11-25
 367793 | 2007-10-02
 369002 | 2006-09-04
 369172 | 1983-09-10
 369256 | 2001-05-19
 369670 | 1992-03-21
 372082 | 2011-07-27
(10 rows)

Time: 15.085 ms
phi=# SELECT P.id, p.resource ->> 'birthDate' BD FROM recorditems P WHERE  P.resource @> '{"resourceType":"Patient", "gender":"male"}' AND To_date(P.resource ->> 'birthDate', 'YYYY-MM-DD') > '1975-01-01'::date limit 10;
   id   |     bd
--------+------------
 372082 | 2011-07-27
 372645 | 1988-11-02
 373528 | 1984-07-11
 376213 | 1982-01-03
 377386 | 1995-01-20
 377531 | 2002-02-11
 377717 | 1991-11-15
 378372 | 2018-09-27
 378483 | 2009-01-11
 378743 | 1996-02-27
(10 rows)

Time: 18.163 ms 
phi=# SELECT P.id, p.resource ->> 'birthDate' BD FROM recorditems P WHERE  P.resource @> '{"resourceType":"Patient", "gender":"male"}' AND To_date(P.resource ->> 'birthDate', 'YYYY-MM-DD') > '1975-01-01'::date limit 10;
   id   |     bd
--------+------------
 378743 | 1996-02-27
 382517 | 1992-01-14
 387866 | 1985-07-03
 388180 | 1976-11-01
 388627 | 1996-07-10
 396668 | 1979-03-29
 396754 | 2013-05-16
 397054 | 1998-01-05
 401771 | 1983-11-28
 401891 | 2019-03-01
(10 rows)

Time: 44.394 ms
```

Comment: Did you try to sort your query results and to test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have multiple sequential scans going against the same table at more or less the same time (loosely defined), PostgreSQL tries to synchronize them so that they can all benefit from the same warmed-up cache.  If you turn off this feature with `set synchronize_seqscans TO off`, you will probably get more predictable results.  But your original sin here is expecting an order, when you didn't request one.

Comment: First, let me confess for the Sin! :) I was expecting some 'natural' order.

Answer (score 1):

You are not sorting your results. A `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` **will** return (seemingly) random results as the rows of a table are not sorted.

If you want to get consistent results using `LIMIT` you **have** to use an `ORDER BY` as well.